Asymptotic integral: which method to use if the Hessian is 0?
I have the following integral that I need to evaluate for $t\gg\Gamma^{-1}$:
$$\int_{0}^{\Gamma} \frac{\omega^{3} \sin(\Omega t) \sin(\omega t) \cos(\omega t) d\omega}{\omega^{4} + 2(\gamma^{2} - \Omega^{2})\omega^{2} + (\Omega^{2} + \gamma^{2})^{2}}.$$
I understand that I can write the trigonometric part as the imaginary part of $\exp(2i\omega t).$ But if I try to use the stationary phase approximation method,the second derivative of the function on the exponential becomes $0$. What other asymptotic methods do I have at my disposal to evaluate this integral in the given limit? And is it possible to evaluate this integral exactly?
EDIT: There is logarithmic divergence (which is apparent from the powers of $\omega$). The answer that the paper gives you is proportional to
$$\ln\Big(\frac{\Gamma^{2}}{\Omega^{2} + \gamma^{2}}\Big).$$
EDIT: This is the DOI of the paper.I think you need an institutional account for access.

Could you add the details of the paper you are talking about?

Reduction of a wave packet in quantum Brownian motion
W. G. Unruh W. H. Zurek

The point is that here you do not need any saddle point method. You only need to think about the integral a bit.
First you rewrite the integral as
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2} \sin(\Omega t) \text{Im }g(t)
$$
Clearly, you can write the full asymptotic expansion in this way not just the leading term as I did.
Above I defined
$$
g(t) = \Gamma^4 \int_0^1 e^{2 i x t \Gamma}\frac{x^3}{\Gamma^4 x^4 + 2(\gamma^2 - \Omega^2) \Gamma^2 x^2 + \Omega^2 + \gamma^2}dx
$$
and I have changed variables $\omega = \Gamma x$.
Then you realize that for $t \Gamma \gg 1$ the exponent only contributes when $x\ll 1$, because otherwise wild oscillations kill the integral.
This lets you expand the the rest of the integrand function as
$$
g(t) \sim \frac{\Gamma^4}{\Omega^2 + \gamma^2} \int_0^1 e^{2i x t \Gamma}x^3dx
$$
which can be explicitly integrated. What you get is
$$
g(t) \sim -\frac{i \, e^{2i \Gamma t }}{2\Gamma t}\frac{\Gamma^4}{\Omega^2+\gamma^2}
$$
from which you easily get
$$
f(t) \sim - \frac{1}{4}\sin(\Omega t)\cos(2 \Gamma t) \frac{\Gamma^4}{\Omega^2 + \gamma^2}\frac{1}{\Gamma t}
$$

This is a good answer. But the paper that I took this from says that there is a logarithmic divergence (which is apparent from the powers of the denominator and numerator) and that I should get something proportional to $\ln\big(\frac{\Gamma^{2}}{\Omega^{2} + \gamma^{2}}\big)$.

@saad Are you referring to eq. (2.19)? I think they are taking a different scaling limit which they call of “intermediate times” because they have different time scales. Also $\gamma t$ is important: the limit of “infinite” time would be $\gamma t\gg 1$ and in that case all exponentials vanish. As per the integral in the question the asymptotic behavior should be the one given above as there is only one time scale $\Gamma$. To be fully confident though it would be appropriate to do a numerical check.
